# Uniqueness of Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

I am studying measure theory using the lectures by Claudio Landim on Youtube.

In lecture 4 he proofs the Caratheodory extension theorem and in particular points out that it is possible to extend a $\sigma$-additive set function defined on an algebra $a$ to a $\sigma$-additive set function defined on the sigma algebra of measurable sets $M$ which satisfy the Caratheodory measurability criterion, i.e. $A \in M$ if
$$\pi^*(E)=\pi^*(E \cap A)+\pi^*(E \cap A^c)$$ where $\pi^*$ denotes the Lebesgue outer measure.

$M$ is usually called the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra and the restriction of the Lebesgue outer measure to the set $M$ is simply referred to as the Lebesgue measure (see for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure#Definition).

However, he also states that we can only prove the uniqueness of the Lebesgue measure on a possibly smaller $\sigma$-algebra $\varphi(a)$ (the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the algebra) under certain conditions I will omit for brevity. Note that $\varphi(a) \subseteq M$ since $M$ contains $a$.

So to sum up we should always consider the Lebesgue measure on $\varphi(a)$ since otherwise it is not clear what we mean by $\pi^*(A)$ for a set $A$.

In lecture 5 he continues by constructing the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ by showing that we can apply the Caratheodory criterion to a $\sigma$-additive set function defined on a suitable algebra.

Now the thing that confuses me is that most theorems and definitions using the Lebesgue measure consider the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra and not $\varphi(a)$.

For example, Lebesgue measurable functions are defined as functions such that the inverse image $f^{-1}(A) \in M$ $\forall A \in B$ where $B$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function#Notable_classes_of_measurable_functions).

Why do we always consider the Lebesgue measure on $M$ when it is not always unqiue? Or is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ a special case? This has been confusing me for quite a while now, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you will find that $\varphi(a)=M$ in the case of the Lebesgue measure, provided that $a$ contains all Borel sets and outer-null sets.

Comment: Thanks @Ian. Do you know any source for such a proof? Or can you give me an idea how one could try to prove this?

Comment: Actually I think that $\varphi \subset M$ since I have proven that $\varphi(a)=B$ and $B$ is not complete and $M$ is its completion. Am I missing something?

Comment: What's $a$, then? I was assuming $a$ contained all the outer-null sets, in which case $\varphi(a)$ will indeed be complete.

Comment: @Ian Sorry if I wasn't clear, but $a$ is an algebra generated by the semi algebra $C$ where $C= \{\emptyset,\mathbb{R},(a,b]:a<b,(-\infty,b],(a,+\infty)\}$. So $\varphi(a)$ should exactly equal $B$ which can be generated by the half open intervals.

Comment: Sure, but there's only one complete extension, which is what we use.

Comment: @Ian Exactly, that's why I was confused, but I simpy forgot that the Caratheodory extension theorem is far more general than the Lebesgue measure. In fact as you've pointed out we can extend it to the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra in a unique way. Thanks again for your comments.